# How do I let a user re-signup using the same username but different email in react-native using aws-amplify authorization?

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

so I am trying to build my first app using react-native and currently trying to add authorization method using cognito. Currently I have succesfully setup signup method with Auth.signUp. However, I realized before confirming signup the username is already in the user pool, thus preventing a user to signup again using the same username(if they typed the wrong email address).
How do I fix this problem?

I am very unsure how to approach this problem and currently surfing the web.

What I have now is this

```
    async signUp() {
      const { username, password, email, phone } = this.state
      const phone_number = phone
      await Auth.signUp({
        username,
        password,
        attributes: { email, phone_number }
      })
```

I want to be able to let user signup again using different email before confirmation.

Comment: You can go into the Cognito Console on AWS and delete the user and have him sign up again.

Comment: Is it possible to delete the user for each prompt of sign up?

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question? I didn't understand it.